# Cannot convert value of type 'CLLocationDirection' (aka 'Double') to expected argument type 'Float'

Tags: xcode, swift, dictionary, compass

I have this code and its giving me and error `Cannot convert value of type 'CLLocationDirection' (aka 'Double') to expected argument type 'Float'` on `arrowImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(self.degreesToRadians(direction)))`. Please help me fix. Thank you.

```
  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {

var direction: CLLocationDirection = newHeading.magneticHeading

if direction > 180 {
  direction = 360 - direction
}
else {
  direction = 0 - direction
}

// Rotate the arrow image
if let arrowImageView = self.arrowImageView {
  UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
    arrowImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(self.degreesToRadians(direction)))

  })
```

And would it also be possible to make the compass point to a longitude and latitude specified by the user? Could you please teach me how. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Might is be that degreesToRadians expects a Float? If so self.degreesToRadians(Float(direction)) might do the trick.

Comment: That did the job mate. Thank you. About my second question. Is it possible to make the compass point to a longitude and latitude specified by the user? Could you please teach me how.

Answer (score 3):

Swift's primitive types are not interchangeable (unlike in Objective-C)

Either you make your `degreesToRadians` function conform also to `Double`
or you have to create a `Float` from `direction`

```
arrowImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(self.degreesToRadians(CGFloat(direction))))
```

Comment: Thank you its already fixed. Another thing, is it possible to make the compass point to a longitude and latitude specified by the user? Could you please teach me how

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with CoreLocation